# Subsets of an array in specific order using iteration method

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, iteration

Create all subsets of an array using iterative method.

{1,2,3,4}

The subsets should be created in specific order:

`{{}, {1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, {2}, {2,3}....}`

1. Creating all subsets from traversing 0 to pow(2,n)-1.
   This does not guarantee the order needed.

How should it be done using iteration?

Comment: What you have tried?  Can you share where do you get stuck or confused?

Comment: Try using the BIT Manipulation technique, loop from 0 to 2^n where n is the length of the array. for each value add the corresponding element from the array into the current set. Ex: i = 2 (0000 0010) add the second element from the array in the current set.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use the algorithm **Depth first search** to solve this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
const int maximumSize=10;
vector<int> numbers={1, 2, 3, 4};
set<vector<int>> combinations;
vector<int> visited(maximumSize, 0);
void showContentSetVector(set<vector<int>> input)
{
    for(auto iterator=input.begin(); iterator!=input.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        cout<<"{";
        for(auto item : *iterator)
        {
            cout<<item<<", ";
        }
        cout<<"}; ";
    }
    return;
}
void dfs(int current, int previous)
{
    if(visited[current]==1)
    {
        return;
    }
    visited[current]=1;
    if(numbers[current]==1)
    {
        vector<int> emptySet;
        combinations.insert(emptySet);
    }
    vector<int> singleItem;
    singleItem.push_back(numbers[current]);
    combinations.insert(singleItem);
    for(int i=(current+1); i<numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
        vector<int> temporary;
        singleItem.push_back(numbers[i]);
        temporary=singleItem;
        combinations.insert(singleItem);
        for(int j=(i+1); j<numbers.size(); ++j)
        {
            temporary.push_back(numbers[j]);
            singleItem.push_back(numbers[j]);
            combinations.insert(singleItem);
            singleItem.pop_back();
            if(j==(numbers.size()-1))
            {
                combinations.insert(temporary);
            }
        }
        singleItem.pop_back();
        temporary.clear();
    }
    for(int next=(current+1); next<numbers.size(); ++next)
    {
        if(next==current)
        {
            continue;
        }
        dfs(next, current);
    }
    if(current==0)
    {
        showContentSetVector(combinations);
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    dfs(0, -1);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
{}; {1, }; {1, 2, }; {1, 2, 3, }; {1, 2, 3, 4, }; {1, 2, 4, }; {1, 3, }; {1, 3, 4, };
{1, 4, }; {2, }; {2, 3, }; {2, 3, 4, }; {2, 4, }; {3, }; {3, 4, }; {4, };
```

Also your problem can be solved without the algorithm **Depth first search**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
vector<int> numbers={1, 2, 3, 4};
set<vector<int>> combinations;
void showContentSetVector(set<vector<int>> input)
{
    for(auto iterator=input.begin(); iterator!=input.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        cout<<"{";
        for(auto item : *iterator)
        {
            cout<<item<<", ";
        }
        cout<<"}; ";
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    for(int current=0; current<numbers.size(); ++current)
    {
        if(numbers[current]==1)
        {
            vector<int> emptySet;
            combinations.insert(emptySet);
        }
        vector<int> singleItem;
        singleItem.push_back(numbers[current]);
        combinations.insert(singleItem);
        for(int i=(current+1); i<numbers.size(); ++i)
        {
            vector<int> temporary;
            singleItem.push_back(numbers[i]);
            temporary=singleItem;
            combinations.insert(singleItem);
            for(int j=(i+1); j<numbers.size(); ++j)
            {
                temporary.push_back(numbers[j]);
                singleItem.push_back(numbers[j]);
                combinations.insert(singleItem);
                singleItem.pop_back();
                if(j==(numbers.size()-1))
                {
                    combinations.insert(temporary);
                }
            }
            singleItem.pop_back();
            temporary.clear();
        }
    }
    showContentSetVector(combinations);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
{}; {1, }; {1, 2, }; {1, 2, 3, }; {1, 2, 3, 4, }; {1, 2, 4, }; {1, 3, }; {1, 3, 4, };
{1, 4, }; {2, }; {2, 3, }; {2, 3, 4, }; {2, 4, }; {3, }; {3, 4, }; {4, };
```